# How to improve listening/speaking if learned mostly by reading/writing?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english, listening, learning, irish-english

My first language is Spanish and I learned English mostly by reading/writing in academics and professional context but few listening and speaking practice. I got a job abroad and after 2 months I still don't understand 100% what people say to me.

- Is this part of the adapting and learning process of moving to an English speaking country?
- Could it be because of the accent and region where I moved?
- How could I improve listening/speaking skills assuming I have enough reading/writing level?

This is my first question here and I would really appreciate any feedback about the question, e.g. it's off-topic, it's better to split it into different questions, etc.

**EDIT 1:**
For more context information:
I am from South-america so I was exposed to american English and I moved to Ireland, which could be quite different.

The aim of this question, more than grammar and the English language itself, is to know about the learning process of English as second language. Once I read something like "Don't judge someone because mispronounce a word, maybe that person learned that word by reading", so I guess my case is common. I am interested in similar experiences and, why not, psychological/medical aspects of learning English. For example, when someone who was deaf starts hearing again.

Comment: First, you might have to get used to the accent, that is, the way they speak. There is no shorcut for it, as there's no shortcut for reading/writing. The only way to get it around is to practice as much as you can, just as you did for reading/writing. That's my opinion as a learner.

Comment: You may want to look at [languagelearning.se] to see if your question is a good fit there. That site focuses more on learning techniques. If your question is on-topic there, you could flag this question for moderator attention and ask to have it migrated.

Comment: Hi, I have checkde Language Learning, but because I am focusing on the nature of English Language, which is irregular (as you write it is not as you pronounce it) I decided to leave the question here. Also, I would like to know the effects of an accent in the listening skills, in this case west Irish accent (Kerry/Limerick). Is it hard to understand even to native English speakers?